# Magento 2.4.3 CatalogSearch blank page when I search something

Tags: magento2, catalog, catalogsearch, elasticsearch

I'm having a problem searching for products.

When I try to perform a search and press the enter key, I am directed to the `catalogsearch/result` page, but the latter is completely empty, without any content (the body is empty, without the header or otherwise HTML elements).

I tried to clean the ElasticSearch indexes, as well as to clean the cache, but nothing, I always get a blank page without HTML. The logs do not report any kind of errors.

That said, I'm using the `Amasty Advanced Search` and `Layered Navigation` modules. In local everything works correctly, the problem I am experiencing is only in the staging area.

How can I solve this problem?

Below is a screenshot of the page

[image]

Comment: Try to check error log files

Comment: Try disabling both extensions and see if the page work. Then enable each extension one by one to figure out which extension is causing the issue.

Comment: Check server logs also.

Comment: Check the magento log files and server log files , please do check if you are in developer mode , because developer mode helps you in displaying the erros when compared to other modes  , also check the network tab by pressing F12 , check the requests and responses if it is having any error.

Answer (score 1):

This is what Magento does well, WSOD (White Screen Of Death) - you have absolutely no idea where the error is :)

I would recommend these 2 steps:

1. php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
2. uncomment app/bootstrap.php:14

And now you should see that mysterious error.
(if not, right click -> show source code -> scroll down)